# Jslint complains about iterating over array

Tags: javascript, jslint

Why does jslint complain about this??

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

The error message is:

```
Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.
```

This makes no sense to me to declare the variable in the wider scope than necessary (does that for block have each own sope btw?).

What is wrong here? If this is just a whim of jslint, is there a possibility to make it somehow ignore this specific case only?

Comment: The `for` loop doesn't have its own scope, only functions do. There is no block scope in JavaScript, just lexical scope. Here's some reading on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions . And I'm sure JSHint suggests this because technically the declaration of `i` is **hoisted** to the top of the scope. You can read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: @Ian There is `let`.

Comment: @simonzack You're right. Unfortunately that's in ES6, and isn't supported in many browsers. You're welcome to comment/answer and explain it more. And it doesn't really help when JSLint can't recognize it

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have block scope, so this:

```
function foo() {

   // some code

   for (var i = 0; i < a.length etc
```

is the same as:

```
function foo() {

   var i;

   // some code

   for (i = 0; i < a.length etc
```

JSLint thinks that you might not be aware of JS scoping rules and suggests that you restructure your source in accordance with how the interpreter actually works - that is, use the second option.

I personally never do that, because out-of-context declarations severely reduce readability:

```
function foo() {

   var i; // what the heck is this for?

   // some code
   // more code
   // even more code

   for (i = 0; i < a.length // where the heck does this come from?
```

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DeclareVariablesAtFirstUse discusses pros and contras of this approach.

Comment: That particular warning might actually be the most cited reason for people to move from JSLint to something else like JSHint, for the reason you stated.